# Unbind all events that a view adds to the app.vent

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

Will the events that I added to the global event bus deleted by calling `view.unbindAll()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you bind them with the `bindTo` method on the Marionette view types, yes:

```
SomeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

  initialize: function(){
    // note the use of the 4th parameter. this is important when binding
    // to the App's event aggregator
    this.bindTo(MyApp.vent, "some:event", this.someCallback, this);
  },

  someCallback: function(){
    // ...
  }
});
```

Closing an instance of SomeView will unbind the event aggregator events, now.

Comment: Thanks. Btw, can I really pass someCallback, not this.someCallback?

Comment: oops - no. `this.someCallback`... it's too early in the morning. :D

Comment: And yet another small question, to I need to pass this as context? Wouldn't it be the default context?

Comment: yes, you need to pass it. callback methods will get set to the global context by default (that's how JavaScript works, not specific to backbone). plus, if you don't pass it, closing the view will unbind all handlers bound to "some:event", not just this view instance.

Comment: bindTo is now replaced by listenTo : https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/issues/423

Comment: I tried the `listenTo()` to bind with MyApp.vent and i had to manually `stopListening()` in the `close()` function.
How should i register the event, so that on close of the view, the event is unbound automatically?
Note: I am using Marionette v 1.0.1